# sliksvn first commit slow second fast

Tags: svn, performance, commit

Ive created a program that needs to commit to repositories. I'm using slikSvn. It seems that the very first commit since the program has been launched (not first ever) I make is very slow (20 sec) but every other commit is much faster more like 1 sec. Is there some kind of connection to slikSvn I can make when I first load my program to avoid this 20 sec commit? 
Please let me know what additional information you need.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first commit has to make a copy of all the files.
Subsequent commits only need to copy the changes.

Other than a faster link - or somehow send the initial copies by some other faster means (sneakernet) there isn't much you can do.

Comment: but both commits are not on the same folder, and it dosen't matter which folder I do first.

Comment: Also this is not the first commit ever, just first commit since the program has been open.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that delay is caused by the clients authentification with the server.
(Does it happen with every first command or just with every first commit?)

If it is authentification-related then you could probably just send a small request to the server when your program loads like "svn list -r0 REP_URL" (this would be for subversion, but I'm sure there is a similar command in slikSvn)

Comment: it seems to just be commits because "svn add" & "svn update" both seem to work at a good speed.

Comment: running list during load did not help. However I think this is the right idea, I just think I need to choose a different command.

Comment: The idea behind "list -r0" was to use a command that doesn't create any output (since it lists revision 0 which should be empty), thus lowering bandwith usage and CPU-time on the server...but maybe you need some output to trigger the delay.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows and there is a limited connectivity to the Internet, then you may notice the delay when running Subversion client command's against a remote repository over HTTPS.

Using a traffic analyzer you could notice, that the delay happens when Windows attempts to access `ctldl.windowsupdate.com` and gets a timeout. Windows attempts to access `ctldl.windowsupdate.com` to check *Certificate Trust List* (i.e. *Certificate Revocation List*). With limited Internet connectivity, Windows may be unable to access it thus resulting in these delays.